# Python - rearranging dataframe data

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, pandas-melt

I wanna rearrange my dataframe from the left one to the right table, like I show you in the next picture:

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"Unnamed:0": ["Entity","","Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4"],
"Unnamed:1": ["A","X","0.45","0.14","0.16","0.28"],
"Unnamed:2": ["A","Y","0.66","0.55","0.39","0.49"],
"Unnamed:3": ["A","Z","0.3","0.24","0.31","0.13"],
"Unnamed:4": ["B","X","0.22","0.08","0.74","0.41"],
"Unnamed:5": ["B","Y","0.94","0.47","0.17","0.16"],
"Unnamed:6": ["B","Z","0.76","0.4","0.93","0.15"],
"Unnamed:7": ["C","X","0.4","0.76","0.71","0.01"],
"Unnamed:8": ["C","Y","0.86","1","0.26","0.32"],
"Unnamed:9": ["C","Z","0.35","0.1","0.36","0.4"],
})
```

I try using `pd.melt`, but I can't get what I want. Ty in advance

Comment: rows to columns ?  its not clear...

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the image, I want that the first two rows (index 0 and 1) will become in columns, and also Entity shoul be a column. I think the image is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your dataframe is not clean (the 2 first rows are a multiindex column name), you can first create the inner dataframe before melting it :

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[2:,1:]).set_index(df.iloc[2:,0])
new_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.iloc[:2,1:].T)
new_df.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index()
```